# Checking for condition in rootframe during Phone App Initialization in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to include a condition in Rootframe initialization based on previous user choice by getting some value from Isolated Storage.

My code:

```
      private void InitializePhoneApplication()
    {
        if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
            return;

        // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
        // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
        RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();

        //I want to check for a condition. Was style option selected by user?

        var appStorage= IsolatedStorage.GetUserStoreforApplication();
        if(appStorage.FileExists("style");
        { 
         RootFrame.Style = Resources["RootFrameStyle"] as Style;

        }
        else {}
         RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
        // Handle navigation failures
        RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

        // Handle reset requests for clearing the backstack
        RootFrame.Navigated += CheckForResetNavigation;

        // Ensure we don't initialize again
        phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
    }
```

I tried normal if-else but the condition always returns true. Is there any other way to check for a condition and then set the RootFrame accordingly?

Comment: What code have you tried? The sample you show doesn't read anything from storage.

Comment: Are you trying to theme the app?

Comment: Yess but not with an image but with a media element.